# Google API - Autocomplete não traz CEP

Tags: android, google-maps

Estou tentando utilizar os serviços do Google para obter endereçamento.  A ideia é informar o endereço ou cep e carregar os dados logradouro, bairro, cep, cidade e estado.

Já consegui obter a maioria dos dados, porém o cep não está sendo retornado no resultado.  Segue a chamada do serviço e o resultado (sendo que alterei a chave para removi, não vai funcionar.  Porém a URI está ok):

[https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?key=removi&components=country:br&input=rua+embaixador+abelardo+bueno](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?key=removi&components=country:br&input=rua%20embaixador%20abelardo%20bueno)

```
    {
   "predictions" : [
      {
         "description" : "Avenida Embaixador Abelardo Bueno - Barra da Tijuca, Rio de Janeiro - RJ, Brasil",
         "id" : "31fc7076c2289ecf1b100f0a769553d5341ac002",
         "matched_substrings" : [
            {
               "length" : 33,
               "offset" : 0
            }
         ],
         "place_id" : "ElBBdmVuaWRhIEVtYmFpeGFkb3IgQWJlbGFyZG8gQnVlbm8gLSBCYXJyYSBkYSBUaWp1Y2EsIFJpbyBkZSBKYW5laXJvIC0gUkosIEJyYXNpbA",
         "reference" : "CmRUAAAAkQ98koLpBb_VEBonelaZ8iCxYEHtJp0sDeH4gtBzgEnkOs4hpwI7Jaxd0Nq7ZAo1pfsWy9YRLWFkIz0D4EyAZC6ncoK-rQ-dTr9lMWVeFqhZTK50x-zweb3LFcb_zAJDEhD7GsVJdIBYX0_ldipY-272GhSqcdx6p9Ml9BgchUoHct1wglHwqQ",
         "structured_formatting" : {
            "main_text" : "Avenida Embaixador Abelardo Bueno",
            "main_text_matched_substrings" : [
               {
                  "length" : 33,
                  "offset" : 0
               }
            ],
            "secondary_text" : "Barra da Tijuca, Rio de Janeiro - RJ, Brasil"
         },
         "terms" : [
            {
               "offset" : 0,
               "value" : "Avenida Embaixador Abelardo Bueno"
            },
            {
               "offset" : 36,
               "value" : "Barra da Tijuca"
            },
            {
               "offset" : 53,
               "value" : "Rio de Janeiro"
            },
            {
               "offset" : 70,
               "value" : "RJ"
            },
            {
               "offset" : 74,
               "value" : "Brasil"
            }
         ],
         "types" : [ "route", "geocode" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
```

Será que o CEP não é retornado mesmo?  Existe algum parâmetro que determine que o CEP precisa ser incluído?

Comment: Até onde eu pesquisei, se você não informar o número da rua, ele não retornará CEP, porque uma mesma rua pode ter diversos CEPs

Comment: Felipe, faz todo sentido.  Mas testando o endereço "Rua Irutim, 86 - Penha Circular, Rio de Janeiro - RJ, Brasil" no link https://jsfiddle.net/api/post/library/pure/ que é fornecido pelo Google, não retorna o CEP.  Obrigado pelo retorno.

Comment: Como posso informar o numero do endereço na URI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema dessa abordagem é que os dados de localidades da Google nem sempre possuem o CEP, como você deve ter percebido.

Portanto, para trabalhar com CEPs, sugestiono o uso de *Web Services* como o [ViaCep](https://viacep.com.br) que possui uma base de dados gigantesca com os CEPs do Brasil todo.

Infelizmente, você terá que obter as informações, atualizar os campos e fazer validações manualmente, porém o funcionamento do *Web Service* é bem simples...

Basta acessar o URL com o endereço e você terá o CEP como retorno.

> https://viacep.com.br/ws/RS/Porto%20Alegre/Domingos+Jose+Poli/json/

```
[
  {
    "cep": "91790-072",
    "logradouro": "Rua Domingos José Poli",
    "complemento": "",
    "bairro": "Restinga",
    "localidade": "Porto Alegre",
    "uf": "RS",
    "unidade": "",
    "ibge": "4314902",
    "gia": ""
  }
]
```

Também funciona de forma inversa: você informa o CEP e o serviço retorna detalhes do endereço.

> https://viacep.com.br/ws/01001000/json/

```
{
  "cep": "01001-000",
  "logradouro": "Praça da Sé",
  "complemento": "lado ímpar",
  "bairro": "Sé",
  "localidade": "São Paulo",
  "uf": "SP",
  "unidade": "",
  "ibge": "3550308",
  "gia": "1004"
}
```

Para os casos onde uma rua pode ter mais de um CEP, o ViaCep irá retornar um array com todos os CEPs disponíveis daquela rua:

> https://viacep.com.br/ws/SP/Sao%20Paulo/Avenida%20Paulista/json/

```
[
  {
    "cep": "01311-909",
    "logradouro": "Avenida Paulista",
    "complemento": "491",
    "bairro": "Bela Vista",
    "localidade": "São Paulo",
    "uf": "SP",
    "unidade": "",
    "ibge": "3550308",
    "gia": "1004"
  },
  {
    "cep": "01311-905",
    "logradouro": "Avenida Paulista",
    "complemento": "347",
    "bairro": "Bela Vista",
    "localidade": "São Paulo",
    "uf": "SP",
    "unidade": "",
    "ibge": "3550308",
    "gia": "1004"
  },
  {
    "cep": "01310-000",
    "logradouro": "Avenida Paulista",
    "complemento": "até 610 - lado par",
    "bairro": "Bela Vista",
    "localidade": "São Paulo",
    "uf": "SP",
    "unidade": "",
    "ibge": "3550308",
    "gia": "1004"
  },
  {
    "cep": "01310-933",
    "logradouro": "Avenida Paulista",
    "complemento": "2444",
    "bairro": "Bela Vista",
    "localidade": "São Paulo",
    "uf": "SP",
    "unidade": "",
    "ibge": "3550308",
    "gia": "1004"
  }
...
```

Comment: Amelco perfeito.  Me parece que a Google não possui os ceps atualizados.  Pensando na colocação do Felipe, podemos ter mais de um cep para a mesma rua, avenida...  Como poderia passar o numero do endereço para o Viacep?  Estou procurando no site e no Google, mas não tive sucesso.  Muito obrigado pela sua solução.

Comment: Acredito que o ViaCep não aceite números na consulta, portanto não será tão preciso quando esperado. Mas consultando pelo nome da rua, cidade e estado, o ViaCep retorna um Vetor com os resultados possíveis.

Ou seja, se a rua tem 2 CEPs, ele deve listar os dois. Cabe a você tratar isso para o usuário.

Comment: Adicionei à resposta essa possibilidade de múltiplos CEPs.